# Make div with position: absolute push down div

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to make a page with a background that scales to the browser width, regardless if the page is greater in height then the browser width, and then place content below the background.

I have achieved this with the background, but I had to use absolute positioning for it to work, so I am having a hard time figuring out how to push down the main container. So either a way to do that, or make the background follow the browser width without the use for absolute positioning.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

[Sitelink](http://www.svenssonsbild.se/Baronen/?page_id=103)

The css of the background div and the main container to be pushed down:

```
#supersized {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#main-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: How can anything be **behind a background**. It's not logical. Please provide your HTML/CSS anda JSFiddle.

Comment: Im not trying to put it **behind** the background, mere **below** the div containing the background.

Comment: @Paulie_D he had mentioned below not behind.

Comment: @user2059370 which one is your background? is it the one with the ID supersized?

Comment: @Neville Nazerane Yes, that correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `main-container` div just outside your `container` div. If you would like to then reduce the space between the content and the background, then you can replace your `main-container` css with something like this:

```
#main-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! Needed to fiddle around with main-container´s css to place it correct, but that was easy. Thanks a lot!